# Есть ли вероятность добавления одновременно при mysql_insert_id(); ?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Интересует технический вопрос может кто сталкивался с mysql_insert_id();

Есть потребность после добавления в базу клиента, добавить дополнительные данные в другую базу например utm меток, естественно тогда надо присвоить id к добавляемым данным utm, id добавленного клиента ранее.

Есть ли вообще вероятность, что два клиента заполнят данные в одну и туже секунду? Или можно спокойно делать?

Comment: > Есть ли вообще вероятность, что два клиента заполнят данные в одну и туже секунду?

Тут есть два варианта:

1. MySQL разрешает только одно подключение в конкретный момент времени и блокирует новые подключения от того же пользователя до тех пор, пока текущее не завершится
2. MySQL разрешает многочисленные подключения и, соответственно, держит для каждого подключения свою сессию со своими данными

т.е. в любом случае race condition БД берет на себя.

Вдобавок

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/mysql-insert-id.html

> ... affected only by statements issued within the current client conn-n

Comment: как понимаю, такой вероятности в принципе не может быть?

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, да

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записи могут быть добавлены практически одновременно, даже попасть в один цикл непосредственно записи на диск. В один и тот же момент времени оказаться на диске они не смогут уже по физическим причинам.

При этом вне зависимости от того насколько одновременно были сделаны запросы на запись - записи получат разные идентификаторы.